# QVector с собственным классом внутри, не получается записать в QDataStream

Tags: qtcreator, qt, c++

Здравствуйте.

Есть свой класс Tile и QVector в виде двумерного массива этих Тile-ов.
Собственно, не получается сохранить QVector в файл с помощью QDataStream. Догадываюсь, что нужно что-то дописать в классе Tile. Только вот что? Заранее спасибо.

```
void Map::saveMap(){

    QVector< QVector <Tile> >  mapTile;

          ...
    {
          QDataStream out(&file);
          out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
          out << mapTile;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте тут:
http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_18477_0.html